# Regex for validating date does not work for february

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have this regex as a part of date validation. The screen interface prompts for entering the date in the format dd-mm-yyyy.

However the regex we have is matching Feb dates as false. Being new to regex I am completely clueless how to go about grokking this and mainly why the problem is being caused?

Here is the regex:

```
/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\-(0[13578]|1[02])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\-(0[13456789]|1[012])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\-02\-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/
```

Edit: This was written by someone else in our webapp and I noticed this as soon as the problem cropped up.

Comment: Are you sure the regex is only for `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: If you're _new_ to regex, how did you manage to write this?  If you copied it from elsewhere, make an attempt to _understand_ what it does before using it.

Comment: Go to www.regular-expressions.info to learn how regexp works. You can also paste it into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and hover your mouse over the pieces, and it will tell you what they do.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562111/looking-for-a-regex-to-validate-cuban-identity-card/21562663#21562663) (that I posted yesterday to a different question) which will help you validate dates.

Comment: Effortless question on my part. Will dig into regex practice sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a pretty awful way to validate dates, but the problem is pretty obvious: the regular expression matches a `/` between the day and month for February dates, when it should instead match a `-`. (Febrary dates in leap years work OK.)

All of the backslash-quoted `-` characters in the regex can do without the backslash; it's just not necessary.

```
/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])-02-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29-02-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/
```

Forcing people to construct a particular date format for the convenience of your software is not very considerate.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, this regexp wants a `/` between the day and month for February, I assume this was a typo.

```
/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\-(0[13578]|1[02])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\-(0[13456789]|1[012])\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\-02\-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\-02\-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/
                                                                                                                                                       ^
```